# Is this proper usage of "safe publication"?

Tags: java, thread-safety

With regards to [Safe Publication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/801993/632951), consider this piece of code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadB t = new ThreadB();
        t.start();
        t.Grab(new Bag("HI"));
    }
}

class Bag {
    private String item; // <-- no final here

    public String Item() {
        return item;
    }

    public Bag(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

class ThreadB extends java.lang.Thread {
    private Bag bag;

    public void Grab(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (bag != null) {
                    System.out.println(bag.Item());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed that thread B sees the item ("HI") in bag,

Or is it true that thread B may in fact see the item in the bag as null, and will never see the item "HI" in the bag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Chapter 3.5. Safe Publication* in [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) contains a very similar example. To cut a long story short: it's not thread safe. ThreadB could see its `bag` reference as `null`. Furthermore, ThreadB could see its `bag` reference as not `null`, but the referenced `Bag`'s `item` field could be seen as `null` by ThreadB.

On my machine sometimes it's an endless loop but I can't reproduce the second scenario when just the `Bag.item` is `null`.

Please note that making the `Bag.item` field `final` does not make it thread-safe, access to `ThreadB.bag` also have to be synchronized:

```
public class ThreadB extends java.lang.Thread {
    private Bag bag;

    public synchronized void setBag(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (bag != null) {
                        System.out.println(bag.getItem());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Or you can use an `AtomicReference`:

```
public class ThreadB extends java.lang.Thread {
    private final AtomicReference<Bag> bag = new AtomicReference<Bag>();

    public void setBag(final Bag bag) {
        this.bag.set(bag);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Bag bag = this.bag.get();
                if (bag != null) {
                    System.out.println(bag.getItem());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

---

Some other notes:

1,

```
public String Item() {
    return item;
}
```

From [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367):

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter
>   lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

So, this method should be called `getItem`:

```
public String getItem() {
    return item;
}
```

2, According to the same document, chapter [File Organization](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141855.html#1852), methods should appear after constructors:

```
public class Bag {
    private String item;

    public Bag(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}
```